# CQRS - Single command handler?

Tags: cqrs

I´m just trying to wrap my head around CQRS(/ES). I have not done anything serious with CQRS. Probably I´m just missing something very fundamental right now. Currently, I´m reading "Exploring CQRS and Event Sourcing". There is one sentence that somehow puzzles me in regards to commands:

"A single recipient processes a command."

I´ve seen this also in the CQRS sample application from Greg Young ([FakeBus.cs](https://github.com/gregoryyoung/m-r/blob/master/SimpleCQRS/FakeBus.cs)) where an exception is thrown when more then one command handler is registered for any command type.

For me, this is an indication that this is a fundamental principle for CQRS (or Commands?). What is the reason? For me, it is somewhat counter-intuitive.

Imagine I have two components that need to perform some action in response to a command (it doesn´t matter if I have two instances of the same component or two independent components). Then I would need to create a handler that delegates the command to these components.

In my opinion, this is introducing an unnecessary dependency. In terms of CQRS, a command is nothing more than a message that is sent. I don´t get the reason why there should be only one handler for this message.

Can someone tell me what I am missing here? There is probably a very good reason for this that I just don´t see right now.

Regards

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I am by no means an expert myself with CQRS, but perhaps I can help shed some light.

> "A single recipient processes a command.", What is the reason?

One of the fundamental reasons for this is transactional consistency.  A command needs to be handled in one discrete (and isolated) part of the application so that it can be committed in a single transaction.  As soon as you start to have multiple handlers, distributing the application beyond a single process (and maintaining transactional consistency) is nearly impossible.  So, while you could design that way, it is not recommended.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

> Imagine I have two components that need to perform some action in response to a command (it doesn´t matter if I have two instances of the same component or two independent components). Then I would need to create a handler that delegates the command to these components.

That's the responsibility of events.

A command must be handled by one command handler and must change the state for a single aggregate root. The aggregate root then raises one or more events indicating that something happened. These events can have multiple listeners that perform desired actions.

For example, you have a `PurchaseGift` command. Your command handler loads the `Purchase` aggregate root and performs the desired operation raising a `GiftPurchased` event. You can have one or more listeners to the `GiftPurchase` event, one for sending an email to the buyer confirming the operation and another to send the gift by mail.

Comment: 1. What if you are using a document database that does not allow transactions?
2. Do you persist domain events or not and if so why?
3. Can commands be processed in a multi-thread environment? (for instance two commands PurchaseGift arrive and are processed by two threads simultaneously)