# Commands always handles in one place?

Tags: nservicebus, cqrs

I've read that, in NServiceBus, commands are always handled in a single place. Is this a general CQRS/event sourcing rule of thumb? If yes, what are the advantages? Why is it a bad idea to scale out command handling nodes?

Comment: see here.  your question is a duplicate of 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21565202/cqrs-single-command-handler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The underlying goal of messaging can help us to achieve loose coupling between components by maintaining the autonomy of each component and logical “Service”.

In general by using explicit naming, it should be clear what it is you expect the message handler to do. Combined with the “Single Responsibility Principle” (SRP) we can achieve better decomposition of our systems. For example, “UpdateUser” means nothing, while “UpdateUserPhoneNumber” or “ChangeUserPassword” is more like it :-).

We want to make sure we don’t mix logical (all this belongs in my Finance “Service” for example) and the physical deployable service (process).
There could be many physical processes (windows services, IIS/WEB processes, WCF, Desktop application) that host parts of a logical “Service” or a mix multiple logical “Services”.

Using the Command/Event semantics clarifies what is the intent and logical boundary of a message.

Commands:
– Internal communication between components inside the boundary of a logical “Service” is done using commands.
– Commands (as the name implies) can command another component within the boundary of the logical “Service”.
– They change the state of the processing component.
– They contain the data and context that the component (handler) needs in order to execute its task.
– Commands are “Sent” (using bus.Send() using NServiceBus) to exactly one component (handler) (one to one communication).

Events:
– Events are used for cross logical “Service” communications.
– They notify of things that happened in the past.
– They are light and contain only reference data like Ids and a small amount of context data.
– Events are published (bus.Publish() using NServiceBus)
– There is only one logical publisher and one or more subscribers.
– Events can also be used inside a logical “Service” between internal loosely coupled components.

To summaries:
Use Commands with data inside you logical “Service” boundary to change state.
Use Events with reference data for cross logical “Service” communications.
Follow the Single Responsibility Principle, it will help reduce the size of your units of work.
Reducing coupling is our objective.

Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1):

A command represents the intention to **change a specific part** of the business state. It makes sense to have only one command handler i.e one place where that functionality is implemented. Also, inside a command handler we implement a business use case which has its own model and boundaries.

You can scale command handlers by adding more endpoints but it's the **same** code running in parallel and it's a risky affair, especially in distributed apps. It's easier and cheaper to scale vertically, but I'd say that very few app types need to scale the command side.

Comment: I wouldn't say that scaling out is "risky" - at least, not in NServiceBus.